# Sort bibliography corresponding to .bib file

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I have created a `.bib` file containing the resources. I'm using `biblatex` with `style=numeric`. I would like to have in my document the numbers order as I have inserted the corresponding resources in the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package option `sorting=none` and add `\nocite{*}` in the preamble. Note that this will also assign numbers to entries you don't cite in the document body.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02,C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yeah thanks...sorting = none resolved my problem

Comment: To me don't work, `sorting=none` sorts by citation order and `sorting=debug` sorts *alphabetically* by **key**. This option doesn't sort by `.bib`